# Given entire function has infinitely many zeros

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

Prove that for any $\lambda \neq 0$ and any polynomial $p(z) \not\equiv 0,$ the function $g(z)=e^{\lambda z}-p(z)$ has infinitely many zeros.

My approach: Suppose to the contrary that $g$ has finitely many zeros, at $a_j$'s (say)
$$g(z)=\prod_{j=1}^{n} (z-a_j).$$
By Hadamard's factorization
$$g(z)=e^{h(z)} \cdot \prod_{j=1}^{n} (z-a_j),$$
for some polynomial $h(z).$ I don't know how to get a contradiction. Any help is much appreicated.

Comment: Seems like great Picard theorem will be useful.

Comment: @user1952009 thank you. I'm sorry but I'm having a hard time comprehending the asymptotic argument.

Comment: $g(z) = e^{h(z)} q(z)$ means that its maximum modulus is of the order of $e^{c r^k} r^n$. Note also that as $Re(\lambda z) \to +\infty: \ \log g(z) \to  \lambda z$, and as $Re(\lambda z) \to -\infty$ :  $\log g(z) \to (n-1)\log z$. it suggests that $\int_{|z| = r} \frac{g'(z)}{g(z)} dz$ grows linearly when $r \to \infty$.

Answer (score 5):

The same approach as in [Showing that $e^z=z$ has infinitely many solutions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/895807/showing-that-ez-z-has-infinitely-many-solutions/895818#895818) can be used:

$h(z) = p(z) e^{-\lambda z}$ has an essential singularity at $z = \infty$,
and has only finitely many zeros. Using [Great Picard's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard_theorem) it follows that 
$h$ takes any non-zero value infinitely often. In particular, 
$h(z) = 1$ has infinitely many solutions.

This is the desired conclusion because $h(z) = 1 \Longleftrightarrow e^{\lambda z} = p(z)$.

Comment: @ Martin R    thank you. This helps. But I was looking for something that avoids Picard theorems.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative proof: If the claim is false then
$$ \tag{*}
  e^{\lambda z} - p(z) = q(z) e^{h(z)}
$$
with non-zero polynomials $p, q$, and an entire function $h$. 
To simplify the notation let us assume that $\lambda = 1$, this is no
loss of generality. Then
$$
  e^{h(z)} = \frac{e^z - p(z)}{q(z)}
$$ 
and for $|z| = r$ sufficiently large, some $m \in \Bbb N$, and positive real constants
$C_1, \ldots, C_4$
$$ e^{\operatorname{Re}h(z)} = 
 \lvert e^{h(z)} \rvert \le C_1 (\lvert e^z \rvert + C_2 r^m)
 \le C_1 ( e^r  + C_2 r^m)  \le C_3 e^r 
$$
and therefore
$$
  \operatorname{Re }h(z) \le C_4 +  r
$$
for  $|z| = r > R_0$. So
$$
A(r) :=\max_{|z|=r}\operatorname{Re}h(z) \le  C_4 +  r
$$
Now use

- [Coefficients of analytic expansion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/784655/coefficients-of-analytic-expansion), or
- [Can the real part of an entire function be bounded above by a polynomial?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1647212/can-the-real-part-of-an-entire-function-be-bounded-above-by-a-polynomial)

to estimate the Taylor coefficients of $h$
in terms of $A(r)$, and conclude that $h$ a polynomial
of degree at most one: $h(z) = az + b$.

Finally, substitute $h$ back into equation $(*)$ and compare the 
growth of the different terms.