# Zeros of the equation $e^z-z$ in the complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

Does $e^z -z$ have any zeros?

By plotting the functions $e^z$ and $z$ in the real line, I have seen that this equation does not have any zeros in the real line. Can the same thing be said for the complex plane? Being an entire function, I know that it assumes every finite complex number except atmost one. But what about the zero? Please help.

Comment: Yes it has infinitely many. Consider the use of the Lambert-W function. The zeroes are of the form$$z_k=-W_k{(-1)}\quad k\in\mathbb{Z}$$For example,$$z_0=-W_0{(-1)}\approx0.3181315052-
1.337235701 i$$

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1910554/42969

Comment: Thank you for your answer.